# Mongo Fetching multiple collections query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am practicing and really new to MongoDb database Query. I have three collections data. One collection is customers, one collection is customer's bag and last collection is customer's cloth. Each of them connect with id. I am using [MongoDB package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) for connection and query. My goal is when the customer's cloth get sell it will look bagId from the bagId I want get customer's information. .I really don't how to query this MongoDB.

**My customer data is like this**

```
_id:058585821193645242
accountNumber:"GI-325202"
address:"Calfornia"
city: "Calfornia"
email: "customer@gmail.com"
firstName:"John"
lastName:"doe"
name: "John doe"
phoneNumber: "0000-000"
customerId: 1200 // this id is connected with my bag collection
```

**This is Bag collection**

```
  bagId:119
  customerId:1200 // this my customer Id
```

**This is my Cloth collection**

```
clothId: 123
bagId: 119 
status: sold. // this is my cloth status

clothId: 123
bagId: 119 
status: not sold. // this is my cloth status
```

Answer (score 0):

Please learn mongodb data modeling first and do not relate with RDBMS.

1. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/
2. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/
3. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/